# iOS 8.3 - Interactive Transitions Ignores UIView Animation Completion Block?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Ever since I updated my device to iOS 8.3, I have not been able to get an interactive transition to complete.

It appears that when I call `cancelInteractiveTransition()` or `finishInteractiveTransition()`, the `completion` block in the animator's `completion` block, which contains the line:

```
transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled())
```

is not called at all most of the time. This causes the entire application to stop reacting to touch and rotation events.

I'm using a subclass of `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`.  `cancelInteractiveTransition()` and `finishInteractiveTransition()` are called when its pan gesture recognizer is in the state `.Ended` or `.Cancelled`.

Is this a bug in iOS 8.3 (since this issue only happened to me after 8.3), or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I am having this exact problem. A little further information I've found empirically is that this issue only comes up when the user performs a very quick pan gesture. If it is slow, the completion block *does* get called. I also found out that once the completion block *doesn't* get called, it never gets called again on future gestures (regardless slow or fast). The actual animation block gets called fine every-time however.

Comment: Did you checked processor utilization when the app stop reacting to touch events?? May be there is an infinite loop getting executed on the main thread.

Comment: When I was diagnosing this problem, I noticed that the gesture's change and ended state events were taking place before `animateTransition` even ran. Somehow, `animateTransition` is happening later than one would ahve thought. So the animation was canceled/finished before it even started! When I used some [kludgy GCD sleight of hand](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31497876/1271826) to make sure that the `.Changed` and `.Ended` updates of the `UIPercentDrivenInteractionTransition` didn't happen until after `animationDuration` was called, and it looks like it's ok.

Comment: Thanks @Rob for the workaround. I eventually settled without the interactive portion. It appears someone has reported this bug to Apple. Please file a dup for rdar://21961293. See http://www.openradar.me/21961293

Answer (score 2):

Try to override animationDidStop and call it from there

```
  override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation!, finished flag: Bool) {
    self.transitionContext?.completeTransition(!self.transitionContext!.transitionWasCancelled())
  }
```

I hope that help you!